# How can I run a Docker container without installing Docker Hub?

Tags: java, docker, containers

How can I run a Docker container without installing Docker Hub?

For example:

1. Is there a library which can execute docker commands from inside another program?
2. Perhaps a lightweight `.exe` which I could distribute with the container to run it?

I am distributing my application to the public and I cannot expect them to have Docker Hub installed. They must be able to download the latest version and simply double click on *something* to start it (such as a `.exe` or `.bat`)

My application is a learning game in Java.

Comment: Does this actually need to be a container, or do you just need a JVM?  Are there prebuilt solutions to run a Java application without separately installing the JRE that make more sense?

Comment: The answer is not necessarily? But because the app is moddable (using Java/JAR files) I'd thought that containerisation would add security, plus it would make it possibly easier to manage the programs resources because I wouldn't need to deal with different OSs.

Comment: But Java is already platform independent, so why would you need to deal with different OSs? Docker would only add obfuscation, not security. If someone decided to see what's inside, a docker container wouldn't be much trouble if they intend to also decompile the classes or whatever it is you're afraid of.

Comment: My thought would be about sandboxing modded code which might not be safe - my understanding is that code executing inside the container is not aware of the parent device, so malicious code wouldn't be able to access the device as a whole. Small worry but it was part of my reasoning.

Comment: So you're afraid of a rogue plugin destroying your user's system. Have you considered `SecurityManager` or did you get the C++ plugins working, which could bypass it? Also some form of signing schemes could work for the plugins on a larger scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker "Hub" is a website. You don't install it.

To run Docker containers, you need to install a Docker **daemon**, regardless of the application code you'd be running. And no, Docker is not secure, nor does it claim to be.

There are other `containerd` implementations for running containers (although, not specifically for Windows), however all will require *installing something*.

If you're distributing a JVM application, then there's plenty of real world examples doing that. Intellij & Eclipse for example are written in Java and don't require Docker, so why would you think you do?

Refer [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Comment: Fair enough, it is the Docker daemon which runs the containers, though I was referring (rightly or wrongly) to the desktop application. I have previously considered using Launch4J to package as an .exe file (though that I think is a question for a different time and would open up a number of new questions). I... don't think that you require Docker to run a Java application... Either way, I think in this question I was looking to find a solution like Podman (again, not something I have looked at greatly), though I think that peoples' suggestions have given enough food for thought. Thanks all!